# How to get DataGridView to render correctly?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've got a DataGridView on a form that loads in some data from a DataTable object when something in a previous step is done (this is a Wizard-type application and this is in a TabControl). When moving from the previous step, there is a file that is put into the DataGridView with a few extra columns added. To clarify: populating the table works *exactly as it should* - there is no issue with the data itself.

My problem here is that when moving from the previous step, the DataGridView doesn't render correctly. It still shows the previous step where the data should be, and only displays the data when I select cells (either individual cells - where it renders that cell (when I mouse over the readonly=false cells or clicking on the readonly=true cells) or selecting the whole table). Screenshots are below:

When the screen is first rendered:

[image: when the screen is first rendered]

When I've selected all the cells:

[image: when the cells are selected]

I've tried programmatically selecting all cells (using `datagridview1.SelectAll()`) after I've populated the DataGridView but that doesn't make any difference. I've also tried using the `datagridview1.Select()` method and setting `datagridview1.CurrentCell = datagridview1.Rows[0].Cells[0]`.

I'm not sure this can be solved with code - is there a way to make sure the cells render properly or is this an issue with my local machine?

Comment: None of this should be necessary. So you need to find out the reason. Is the DGV in a `TabPage`? They tend to block display updates until the page is selected. Usually calling `datagridview1.Refresh()` is enough..

Comment: @TaW It is in a `TabPage` but the `Refresh()` method isn't updating it... Is there another way I can refresh the UI?

Comment: __When__ do you call the Refresh? It needs to be called __after__ the Page is shown!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you loaded the data while the container was hidden in an **unselected** `TabPage` it's display updates are blocked.

To bring it to live you can code the `Selected` event:

```
private void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control ctl in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls) ctl.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: I've used this code exactly but I'm still getting the same issue. I've tried refreshing all the controls in the `Selected` event and the `SelectedIndexChanged` event with no luck...

Comment: Hm, strange. Please, for a __test__ only, put a `Button` on the page and a `datagridview1.Refresh();` in its click event. - Also: the above code __assumes__ that the DGV is sitting __directly__ on the TabPage, __not nested__ in any other control, like a Groupbx, a Panel, a Slittcontainer or any other container!

Comment: That worked! I'm going to experiment with putting the `Refresh()` function in various calls - maybe a `tabPage1.Focus()` sort of thing. Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: Little late on my part, didn't get round to fixing this for ages. Putting that line in the tabControl1_Selected event seemed to fix everything once I'd left it alone for a while? To anyone trying to fix the same issue, it's worth playing around with the line in the answer above in different events just to see what works. Thanks for your help!